# R - SQL query with R-Base functions and clause HAVING

Tags: sql, r, count, where-clause, having

I am using library `nycflights13`. How to output results of following query:

```
SELECT engine, COUNT(*) FROM planes WHERE seats > 300 GROUP BY engine HAVING COUNT(*) > 20
```

but `WITHOUT` external library? (I know how to do it with `dplyr` or `sqldf`). Only `R-Base` function?

Answer (score 0):

```
z <- as.data.frame(table(planes$engine[planes$seats > 300]))

z[z$Freq > 20,]

#       Var1 Freq
#1 Turbo-fan  190
```